# i want result, python selenium filter

Tags: python, selenium, filter

I want to filter `td`

**HTML:**

```
<tbody id="list_shop">
<tr><td><a href="shop1">ABC</a></td><td class="today_money">13,841</td></tr>

<tr><td><a href="shop2">DFG</a></td><td class="today_money">34,158</td></tr>

<tr><td><a href="shop3">HIJ</a></td><td class="today_money">35,184</td></tr>

<tr><td><a href="shop4">KLM</a></td><td class="today_money">42,501</td></tr>

<tr><td>SUM</td><td class="today_money">125,684</td></tr>
```

**I Try This (failed):**

```
a = soup.select('#list_shop')
for b in a:
    ab = a.select('#list_shop > tr > td')
    print(ab)
```

**I want as result:**

```
ABC 13,841
DFG 34,158
HIJ 35,184
KLM 42,501
SUM 125,684
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Selenium I would do this :

**CSS_SELCTOR** :

```
tbody#list_shop td
```

use it like this :

```
driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tbody#list_shop td")
```

this will give you a list of all td's (**WebElement**) :

```
for td in driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tbody#list_shop td"):
    print(td.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
```